# How to rewrite url in php using htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

In my website I would like to change the url to `domainname/username`. But my default url is `domainname/index.php?name=username` . I have created a htaccess file in var/www/html/.htaccess and I add the code

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ index.php?name=$1
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/$ index.php?name=$1
```

can anyone please solve this...
Thanks in advance

Comment: What is the problem here? You haven't specified if it isn't working, or if you are getting an error. Side-tip, you only need to use one line, making the slash optional: `^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/?$ index.php?name=$1 [L]`

Comment: I use the above code but the following error displayed.                                    Object not found!

The requested URL was not found on this server. The link on the referring page seems to be wrong or outdated. Please inform the author of that page about the error.

If you think this is a server error, please contact the webmaster.

Error 404

Comment: Do you have mod_rewrite enabled in Apache and `AllowOverride All` for .htaccess files in Apache?

Comment: Panama Jack is correct.  And does it work if you type in the url manually?

Comment: @Syam What do you want to do with URLs that don't match domain/username pattern (for example domain/sometingelse.php or domain/username/image.jpg)?

Comment: @PanamaJack I have enabled both mod_rewrite and AllowOverride All. But it does not work

Comment: @rfportilla How to do manually?(domainname/username or domainname/index.php?name=username) The second method is working when logged(path).

Comment: @dusan.bajic can you please tell me the pattern for domain/username

Comment: Your pattern is fine, if it does not work then you have some other problem. You can add [R=301] at the end of the rule for testing, so you can observe new url in address bar: `RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ index.php?name=$1 [R=301]`

Comment: @dusan.bajic I have edited the code  to this                                       RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ index.php?name=$1 [R=301]    But the url does not change. Is there any change in the link. My link is           index.php?name=$c

Comment: Syam, when you open your browser (with the blank address bar), what **exactly** are you typing in the address bar? What happens when you hit ENTER?

Comment: @dusan.bajic my address bar link is index.php?name=$c and i added the above code to htaccess file. when i executes the file the url displays the same. didn't change to domain name/ username

Comment: What is your apache version

Comment: @dusan.bajic Apache/2.4.12 (Win32) OpenSSL/1.0.1l PHP/5.6.8

Answer (score 0):

This?

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} name=(.+)
RewriteRule ^index\.php %1? [R=301]
```

Comment: The above Code works for me but the page didn't display...   The following error message displayed                                                   Object not found! The requested URL was not found on this server. The link on the referring page seems to be wrong or outdated. Please inform the author of that page about the error. If you think this is a server error, please contact the webmaster. Error 404 –

Comment: Please ask another question since the error you describe have obviously nothing to do with the original question.

Comment: If you just type in the url in the form of 'domainname/index.php?name=username', does it work?

Comment: @rfportilla when i type url in the form of 'domainname/index.php?name=username' then it will automatically redirect to 'domainname/username' but object not found error message is displayed

Comment: THen it sounds like it is working.  If the page is not coming up when you type in domainname/username, then it is a different issue.  I would suggest opening a different question so that this post stays focused on one issue.